# 'goapprtc' works on Google Appengine but not locally

Tags: google-app-engine, go, webrtc

I'm working with '[goapprtc](https://github.com/dgv/goapprtc.appspot.com)' without any code change.

When I delployed it on Google Appengine, it works very well. But when I run it on local server with 'dev_appserver.py':

```
dev_appserver.py goapprtc --host 0.0.0.0
```

remote two peers can connect to server, but cannot meet together.
They show only themselves, and 'connecting' message remain bottom.
I stopped firewall of local server, but the result was same.

1) So, why is that? What should I care about? Is this a problem with TURN Server or something?

2) If I want to run this server without 'dev_appserver.py', how can I modify the code? What packages can I use instead of 'appengine' packages:

```
"appengine"
"appengine/channel"
"appengine/datastore"
"appengine/urlfetch"
```

Command line messages here:

```
C:\>dev_appserver.py goapprtc.appspot.com-master --host 0.0.0.0
INFO     2015-08-24 16:14:08,477 sdk_update_checker.py:229] Checking for updates
 to the SDK.
INFO     2015-08-24 16:14:10,634 sdk_update_checker.py:257] The SDK is up to dat
e.
INFO     2015-08-24 16:14:10,711 api_server.py:205] Starting API server at: http
://localhost:49641
INFO     2015-08-24 16:14:10,727 dispatcher.py:197] Starting module "default" ru
nning at: http://0.0.0.0:8080
INFO     2015-08-24 16:14:10,727 admin_server.py:118] Starting admin server at:
http://localhost:8000
2015/08/24 16:15:02 INFO: Applying media constraints: &{true true}
2015/08/24 16:15:02 INFO: User 66666666 added to room 1234
2015/08/24 16:15:02 INFO: Room 1234 has state &{66666666  false false}
INFO     2015-08-24 16:15:02,305 module.py:808] default: "GET /?r=1234 HTTP/1.1"
 200 1681
INFO     2015-08-24 16:15:02,384 module.py:808] default: "GET /css/main.css HTTP
/1.1" 304 -
INFO     2015-08-24 16:15:02,390 module.py:808] default: "GET /js/main.js HTTP/1
.1" 304 -
INFO     2015-08-24 16:15:02,391 module.py:808] default: "GET /js/adapter.js HTT
P/1.1" 304 -
INFO     2015-08-24 16:15:02,394 module.py:808] default: "GET /images/goapprtc.g
if HTTP/1.1" 304 -
2015/08/24 16:15:03 INFO: User 66666666 connected to room 1234
2015/08/24 16:15:03 INFO: Room 1234 has state &{66666666  true false}
INFO     2015-08-24 16:15:03,486 module.py:808] default: "POST /_ah/channel/conn
ected/ HTTP/1.1" 200 -
2015/08/24 16:15:26 INFO: Applying media constraints: &{true true}
2015/08/24 16:15:26 INFO: User 44444444 added to room 1234
2015/08/24 16:15:26 INFO: Room 1234 has state &{66666666 44444444 true false}
INFO     2015-08-24 16:15:26,638 module.py:808] default: "GET /?r=1234 HTTP/1.1"
 200 1691
INFO     2015-08-24 16:15:26,796 module.py:808] default: "GET /css/main.css HTTP
/1.1" 304 -
INFO     2015-08-24 16:15:26,801 module.py:808] default: "GET /js/main.js HTTP/1
.1" 304 -
INFO     2015-08-24 16:15:26,802 module.py:808] default: "GET /js/adapter.js HTT
P/1.1" 304 -
INFO     2015-08-24 16:15:26,805 module.py:808] default: "GET /images/goapprtc.g
if HTTP/1.1" 304 -
2015/08/24 16:15:28 INFO: User 44444444 connected to room 1234
2015/08/24 16:15:28 INFO: Room 1234 has state &{66666666 44444444 true true}
INFO     2015-08-24 16:15:28,387 module.py:808] default: "POST /_ah/channel/conn
ected/ HTTP/1.1" 200 -
2015/08/24 16:15:29 INFO: Delivered message to user 66666666
INFO     2015-08-24 16:15:29,716 module.py:808] default: "POST /message?r=1234&u
=44444444 HTTP/1.1" 200 -
2015/08/24 16:15:29 INFO: Delivered message to user 66666666
INFO     2015-08-24 16:15:29,806 module.py:808] default: "POST /message?r=1234&u
=44444444 HTTP/1.1" 200 -
2015/08/24 16:15:30 INFO: Delivered message to user 66666666
INFO     2015-08-24 16:15:30,772 module.py:808] default: "POST /message?r=1234&u
=44444444 HTTP/1.1" 200 -
2015/08/24 16:15:30 INFO: Delivered message to user 66666666
INFO     2015-08-24 16:15:30,871 module.py:808] default: "POST /message?r=1234&u
=44444444 HTTP/1.1" 200 -
2015/08/24 16:15:30 INFO: Delivered message to user 66666666
INFO     2015-08-24 16:15:30,938 module.py:808] default: "POST /message?r=1234&u
=44444444 HTTP/1.1" 200 -
2015/08/24 16:15:30 INFO: Delivered message to user 66666666
2015/08/24 16:15:30 INFO: Delivered message to user 66666666
2015/08/24 16:15:30 INFO: Delivered message to user 66666666
INFO     2015-08-24 16:15:30,967 module.py:808] default: "POST /message?r=1234&u
=44444444 HTTP/1.1" 200 -
INFO     2015-08-24 16:15:30,970 module.py:808] default: "POST /message?r=1234&u
=44444444 HTTP/1.1" 200 -
INFO     2015-08-24 16:15:30,970 module.py:808] default: "POST /message?r=1234&u
=44444444 HTTP/1.1" 200 -
2015/08/24 16:15:31 INFO: Delivered message to user 66666666
INFO     2015-08-24 16:15:31,825 module.py:808] default: "POST /message?r=1234&u
=44444444 HTTP/1.1" 200 -
2015/08/24 16:15:31 INFO: Delivered message to user 66666666
INFO     2015-08-24 16:15:31,927 module.py:808] default: "POST /message?r=1234&u
=44444444 HTTP/1.1" 200 -
2015/08/24 16:15:31 INFO: Delivered message to user 66666666
INFO     2015-08-24 16:15:31,996 module.py:808] default: "POST /message?r=1234&u
=44444444 HTTP/1.1" 200 -
2015/08/24 16:15:32 INFO: Delivered message to user 66666666
2015/08/24 16:15:32 INFO: Delivered message to user 66666666
INFO     2015-08-24 16:15:32,065 module.py:808] default: "POST /message?r=1234&u
=44444444 HTTP/1.1" 200 -
2015/08/24 16:15:32 INFO: Delivered message to user 66666666
INFO     2015-08-24 16:15:32,069 module.py:808] default: "POST /message?r=1234&u
=44444444 HTTP/1.1" 200 -
INFO     2015-08-24 16:15:32,075 module.py:808] default: "POST /message?r=1234&u
=44444444 HTTP/1.1" 200 -
2015/08/24 16:15:32 INFO: Delivered message to user 44444444
INFO     2015-08-24 16:15:32,104 module.py:808] default: "POST /message?r=1234&u
=66666666 HTTP/1.1" 200 -
2015/08/24 16:15:32 INFO: Delivered message to user 44444444
INFO     2015-08-24 16:15:32,121 module.py:808] default: "POST /message?r=1234&u
=66666666 HTTP/1.1" 200 -
2015/08/24 16:15:32 INFO: Delivered message to user 44444444
INFO     2015-08-24 16:15:32,147 module.py:808] default: "POST /message?r=1234&u
=66666666 HTTP/1.1" 200 -
2015/08/24 16:15:32 INFO: Delivered message to user 44444444
2015/08/24 16:15:32 INFO: Delivered message to user 44444444
2015/08/24 16:15:32 INFO: Delivered message to user 44444444
INFO     2015-08-24 16:15:32,188 module.py:808] default: "POST /message?r=1234&u
=66666666 HTTP/1.1" 200 -
INFO     2015-08-24 16:15:32,190 module.py:808] default: "POST /message?r=1234&u
=66666666 HTTP/1.1" 200 -
INFO     2015-08-24 16:15:32,191 module.py:808] default: "POST /message?r=1234&u
=66666666 HTTP/1.1" 200 -
2015/08/24 16:15:32 INFO: User 44444444 removed from room 1234
2015/08/24 16:15:32 INFO: Room 1234 has state &{66666666  true false}
2015/08/24 16:15:32 INFO: Sent BYE to 66666666
2015/08/24 16:15:32 WARNING: User 44444444 disconnected from room 1234
INFO     2015-08-24 16:15:32,848 module.py:808] default: "POST /_ah/channel/disc
onnected/ HTTP/1.1" 200 -
INFO     2015-08-24 16:15:32,904 module.py:808] default: "POST /message?r=1234&u
=44444444 HTTP/1.1" 200 -
2015/08/24 16:15:32 INFO: User 66666666 removed from room 1234
2015/08/24 16:15:32 INFO: Room 1234 has state &{  false false}
2015/08/24 16:15:32 WARNING: User 66666666 disconnected from room 1234
INFO     2015-08-24 16:15:32,969 module.py:808] default: "POST /_ah/channel/disc
onnected/ HTTP/1.1" 200 -
INFO     2015-08-24 16:15:33,022 module.py:808] default: "POST /message?r=1234&u
=44444444 HTTP/1.1" 200 -
INFO     2015-08-24 16:15:33,082 module.py:808] default: "POST /message?r=1234&u
=44444444 HTTP/1.1" 200 -
INFO     2015-08-24 16:15:33,131 module.py:808] default: "POST /message?r=1234&u
=66666666 HTTP/1.1" 200 -
INFO     2015-08-24 16:15:33,151 module.py:808] default: "POST /message?r=1234&u
=66666666 HTTP/1.1" 200 -
INFO     2015-08-24 16:15:33,183 module.py:808] default: "POST /message?r=1234&u
=44444444 HTTP/1.1" 200 -
INFO     2015-08-24 16:15:33,191 module.py:808] default: "POST /message?r=1234&u
=44444444 HTTP/1.1" 200 -
INFO     2015-08-24 16:15:33,206 module.py:808] default: "POST /message?r=1234&u
=66666666 HTTP/1.1" 200 -
INFO     2015-08-24 16:15:33,213 module.py:808] default: "POST /message?r=1234&u
=44444444 HTTP/1.1" 200 -
INFO     2015-08-24 16:15:33,220 module.py:808] default: "POST /message?r=1234&u
=66666666 HTTP/1.1" 200 -
INFO     2015-08-24 16:15:33,223 module.py:808] default: "POST /message?r=1234&u
=66666666 HTTP/1.1" 200 -
INFO     2015-08-24 16:15:33,957 module.py:808] default: "POST /message?r=1234&u
=44444444 HTTP/1.1" 200 -
2015/08/24 16:15:34 ERROR: datastore: datastore: no such entity
2015/08/24 16:15:34 WARNING: Unexpected Connect Message to room 1234
INFO     2015-08-24 16:15:34,072 module.py:808] default: "POST /_ah/channel/conn
ected/ HTTP/1.1" 200 -
INFO     2015-08-24 16:15:34,148 module.py:808] default: "POST /message?r=1234&u
=66666666 HTTP/1.1" 200 -
INFO     2015-08-24 16:15:34,170 module.py:808] default: "POST /message?r=1234&u
=66666666 HTTP/1.1" 200 -
INFO     2015-08-24 16:15:34,239 module.py:808] default: "POST /message?r=1234&u
=66666666 HTTP/1.1" 200 -
INFO     2015-08-24 16:15:34,243 module.py:808] default: "POST /message?r=1234&u
=66666666 HTTP/1.1" 200 -
INFO     2015-08-24 16:15:34,243 module.py:808] default: "POST /message?r=1234&u
=66666666 HTTP/1.1" 200 -
INFO     2015-08-24 16:15:34,346 module.py:808] default: "POST /message?r=1234&u
=66666666 HTTP/1.1" 200 -
INFO     2015-08-24 16:15:35,153 module.py:808] default: "POST /message?r=1234&u
=66666666 HTTP/1.1" 200 -
INFO     2015-08-24 16:15:35,183 module.py:808] default: "POST /message?r=1234&u
=66666666 HTTP/1.1" 200 -
2015/08/24 16:15:35 ERROR: datastore: datastore: no such entity
2015/08/24 16:15:35 WARNING: Unexpected Connect Message to room 1234
INFO     2015-08-24 16:15:35,255 module.py:808] default: "POST /_ah/channel/conn
ected/ HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

Thank you for reading.
Sorry for poor question!